# Unable to connect to postgresql setup on a docker container from Java code

Tags: postgresql, docker, jdbc

I have installed a postgres image on a docker container -

I also installed pgadmin and connected the postgres and pgadmin by adding them to a docker network. I am able to connect to the db via pgadmin

I now want to access this local-postgres instance from within my java code, but I get an error that the connection attempt failed.

What am I missing here?

```
docker run --name pgadmin -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=abc@xxx.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin" -p 5050:80 -d dpage/pgadmin4 

docker network create --driver bridge pgnetwork

docker network connect pgnetwork local-postgres

docker network connect pgnetwork pgadmin
```

below are the application.properties file settings

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://local-postgres:5432/db-java-docker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running your java application via Docker inside of `pgnetwork`? If not, the `local-postgres` hostname will not resolve. If you don't want to run the java application via docker, you'll have to give the postgres port a mapped host port that will let you resolve it via localhost. Here's an example:

```bash
# Maps the postgres port to port 5051 on your localhost
$ docker run \
  --name local-postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=db-java-docker \
  -p 5051:5432 \
  postgres:14
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5051/db-java-docker
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that you forgot to add to your config file login and password for db:

`spring.datasource.username: DB_USERNAME`

`spring.datasource.password: DB_PASSWORD`

where DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD so that you created docker postgres container

Comment: it is added in, i just didnt paste them here.

Comment: i suppose that my cod is unable locate the db, possibly because I am not giving the right connection parameters, or because the docker network

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: local-postgres

Comment: try spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db-java-docker
or spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db-java-docker

Comment: localhost did the trick!! Thanks!